# Get element when resampling by Day Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get all the other columns when i applied a min to a resampled by day dataframe.

```
    ts  value   date    diff
date                
2017-09-18 05:40:00 1505706000000000    71  2017-09-18 05:40:00 NaN
2017-09-18 05:30:00 1505705400000000    72  2017-09-18 05:30:00 1.0
2017-09-18 05:20:00 1505704800000000    71  2017-09-18 05:20:00 -1.0
2017-09-18 05:10:00 1505704200000000    73  2017-09-18 05:10:00 2.0
2017-09-18 05:00:00 1505703600000000    72  2017-09-18 05:00:00 -1.0
2017-09-18 04:50:00 1505703000000000    72  2017-09-18 04:50:00 0.0
2017-09-18 04:40:00 1505702400000000    71  2017-09-18 04:40:00 -1.0
2017-09-18 04:30:00 1505701800000000    71  2017-09-18 04:30:00 0.0
```

what i want to do is foreach day get for the min difference the date with all its precision ( no resampled )

but when i do this :

```
df['diff'].resample('D').min()
```

i get this result:

```
date
2016-06-16     9.0
2016-06-17    11.0
2016-06-18    10.0
2016-06-19     NaN
2016-06-20    18.0
2016-06-21     3.0
2016-06-22     NaN
2016-06-23     NaN
2016-06-24     NaN
2016-06-25     NaN
2016-06-26     NaN
2016-06-27    14.0
2016-06-28     9.0
```

the result wanted :

```
date
2016-06-16     9.0  2016-06-16 07:10:00
2016-06-17    11.0  2016-06-17 08:30:00
```

Any idea how to get it the result above ?

Comment: your "result" isn't present in your provided input.

Comment: Yes because it's a sample i can't actually put here all the data since it's one year long with 10 minutes granularity, but what i want to point out is that i want the date with minute and hour precision alongside the resampled date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `merge` of resulting min *diff* series (casted to dataframe) with original dataframe using a *date_only* field to match the resampled index output.

Below also shows with your posted example that multiple data records will result if various hour/minutes in same day share same min *diff* values.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''    
date          ts  value   date2    diff      
"2017-09-18 05:40:00" 1505706000000000    71  "2017-09-18 05:40:00" None
"2017-09-18 05:30:00" 1505705400000000    72  "2017-09-18 05:30:00" 1.0
"2017-09-18 05:20:00" 1505704800000000    71  "2017-09-18 05:20:00" -1.0
"2017-09-18 05:10:00" 1505704200000000    73  "2017-09-18 05:10:00" 2.0
"2017-09-18 05:00:00" 1505703600000000    72  "2017-09-18 05:00:00" -1.0
"2017-09-18 04:50:00" 1505703000000000    72  "2017-09-18 04:50:00" 0.0
"2017-09-18 04:40:00" 1505702400000000    71  "2017-09-18 04:40:00" -1.0
"2017-09-18 04:30:00" 1505701800000000    71  "2017-09-18 04:30:00" 0.0
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=0, parse_dates=[0,3])\ 
                  .rename(columns={'date2':'date'})
df['date_only'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.to_series().dt.date)

new_df = df['diff'].resample('D').min()\
           .to_frame()\
           .reset_index()\
           .merge(df, left_on=['date', 'diff'], right_on=['date_only', 'diff'],
                  suffixes=['','_'])[['date', 'diff', 'date_']]\
           .set_index('date')\
           .rename(columns={'date_':'date'})

print(new_df)
#             diff                date
# date                                
# 2017-09-18  -1.0 2017-09-18 05:20:00
# 2017-09-18  -1.0 2017-09-18 05:00:00
# 2017-09-18  -1.0 2017-09-18 04:40:00
```